# What security risk is not having "default" theme?

Tags: themes

I always develop my own templates and remove the 22, 21 and 20 templates as well as "Hallo Doly" and the superfluous pages and posts.

After that a warning is displayed under site health 'Have a default theme available'. I have no use for these templates but how do I rid the site of the warning?

Comment: It's not a security risk. It is just a tool for troubleshooting and something to revert to if something goes wrong with the active theme. I do the same as you- delete everything but the default 20xx theme - I can post an answer but it's a workaround and does not "fix" the bug per se - you just won't get the notification. Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

In case you wanted to try - here is the code snippet to add to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'theme-folder-name');
define('CORE_UPGRADE_SKIP_NEW_BUNDLED', true);
```

Comment: Adding the WP_DEFAULT_THEME constant did indeed make the message go away. What is the effect of the other constant?

Comment: The skip-new-bundled definition keeps WordPress from re-adding default plugins and themes for every major upgrade.